# How to do dynamic drawing from inside of VID

Tags: red

I have some code that is supposed to do some drawing from inside VID. People have suggested using the draw block for using it inside VID.  I am trying to do that here, but perhaps not correctly.

Here is some code that shows the basic idea of what I am trying to do.

```
Red [Needs: 'View]
Consolas: make font! [size: 11 name: "Consolas" style: 'bold]
win: [ size 600x400

a: area 460x400 rate 0:0:3 on-time [

        a/draw [
            font Consolas
            text 10x20  "Miter"
            text 170x20 "Round"
            text 330x20 "Bevel"
        ]
    ]
]
view win
```

This code does not create any errors, but does not do any drawing.
How can I change the code to actually do the drawing?

The key here is that I am trying to do drawing conditionally based on other factors which will help to determine what is supposed to be drawn. But if I can't get this working, there's no hope for adding in logic.

Comment: Both are incorrect, it should be: `Red [Needs: 'View]`. Such property in the header matters only if the user wants to compile the code to a standalone executable, otherwise it is not required for running the script from the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a correct version of your code:

```
Red [Needs: 'View]

Consolas: make font! [size: 11 name: "Consolas" style: 'bold]

view [
    size 600x400
    a: base 460x400 draw [
        font Consolas
        text 10x20  "Miter"
        text 170x20 "Round"
        text 330x20 "Bevel"
    ]
]
```

I have made the following changes:

- `area` creates a text area native widget that does not support drawing, so it is replaced by `base` which is the generic face supporting drawing.
- `rate 0:0:3` and `on-time` handler together create a timer that will evaluate the handler every 3 seconds, so irrelevant here.
- `a/draw` is not the correct [syntax](https://doc.red-lang.org/en/vid.html#_draw) for specifying a draw block as option to a face definition in VID.
- The `win:` word setting has been removed, and the VID block is fed to `view` directly for sake of simplicity in this case.

You can join our Gitter [help room](https://gitter.im/red/help) if you need more help in learning Red and its GUI system.

Comment: I appreciate the thought. The documentation on the Face object said that the draw facet was applicable for all.

Comment: The thing, I am not trying to draw something static. I am trying to draw something whose contents will depend on the contents of the area block. Having to draw in another block somewhat throws a wrench in my plans. But more importantly, I wish I saw documentation on how to draw stuff dynamically, every example is static text. The contents of the Draw block are never determined/evaluated at runtime in any example.

Comment: The content of Draw is *always* evaluated at runtime, so you can achieve dynamic effects by simply modifying the `a/draw` block in an event handler.